# Why does this "and-or" ternary expression syntax work?

Tags: python, ternary-operator

I have recently been learning and working with Python, and came across the following code, which I was told is a common shorthand for a ternary expression in Python:

```
x = condition and expression1 or expression2
```

Now I'm familiar with the `? :` operators in C-like languages, and with Python's usual ternary expression `x = expression1 if condition else expression2`, but this new expression seemed a bit odd to me.

Part of my confusion is that it doesn't seem very readable, i.e. when I read that line it doesn't immediately make it clear what is happening, but the other part is that I don't quite understand why it works.

In summary: **Why does the expression above function the same as a C-like ternary expression?**

Comment: It's more boolean that ternary.

Comment: It is being used in the same way that a C-like ternary statement is used, and I would like to know why it works as one.

Comment: "Common shorthand" really? It fails for: `True and 0 or 1`.

Comment: This sort of code is best avoided as it relies on side-effects, just use a real ternary or an if statement.  Others, and your later self will thank you.

Comment: I agree with the sentiment of other commenters that this is neither common practice nor maybe good practice in Python. Although this "trick" is featured in otherwise good intros to the language like "Dive Into Python", it really flies in the face of the Zen of Python unless you're very comfortable with Boolean logic (most people are not).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `and` operator evaluates its right operand (`expression1`) if and only if the left operand is true. Likewise the `or` operator evaluates its right operand (`expression2`) if and only if its left operand is false.

So if `condition` is true, `expression1` gets evaluated. Assuming it evaluates to something truthy, the expression `condition and expression1` is going to be true and `expression2` will thus not be evaluated.

If `condition` is false, `expression1` does not get evaluated and `condition and expression1` is false. So `expression2` will be evaluated.

The only problem would be if `condition` is true, but `expression1` evaluates to something falsy. In that case both `expression1` and `expression2` would be evaluated. So this construct is broken when that's a possibility.

Comment: Right. So it's a mix of short-circuiting and non-boolean operands to `and` and `or` that cause this to work. I was getting confused because I assumed that logical operators such as `and` and `or` only accepted booleans as operands, and evaluated as boolean expressions.

Comment: Interesting. My take-home from both the question and answer is that it is not readable, nor is it safe. So, best avoided then?

Comment: @Darragh Yes, avoid. There's no point in using this over `foo if bar else baz` or a regular `if` statement.

Comment: @Darragh That depends on the context. They are not equivalent. Perhaps someone needs this kind of expression.

Comment: @freakish I assume there was an implied "as a substitute for if-else" here. Of course it's perfectly fine to do something like `if x==1 and y==2 or z==3:`.

Comment: @sepp2k Yes, it's not a substitute. And I think that this should be emphasized. OP assumed that these two are equivalent and they are not. And from that perspective it is neither unsafe nor unreadable. It simply does something different. Of course it might have been a mistake as well.

Comment: This is exactly the reason **Explicit is better than implicit**. `p = x and y or z` is very rarely the most readable way of saying what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

The real reason this works in Python is that these operators are short circuited and execution is left to right.  If there is already enough information to answer the boolean expression the rest of the operands are not executed.  This will not work as expected if `expression1` returns false, it will execute both expressions.

The most common use of this is the statement with only one operator

```
condition and expression
```

That evaluates the `expression` if `condition` is true, the related statement using `or` executes the `expression` if `condition` is false.

This doesn't work in all languages, for example APL would evaluate all the operands.

Comment: +1 for the language design perspective (lends more weight to the idea that this is implicit trickery, contrary to the Zen).

Answer (score 0):

`and` operator returns the left operand if it is falsy and the right operand if the left operand is truthy.

Conversly `or` operator returns the left operand if it is truthy and the right operand if the left one is falsy.

Example:

```
>>> [] and "test"  # [] is falsy
[]
>>> [] or "test"
"test"
>>> "foo" and "bar"  # "foo" is truthy
"bar"
>>> "foo" or "bar"
"foo"
```

As noted by other people these two constructs are not equivalent:

```
>>> True and 0 or 1
1
>>> 0 if True else 1
0
```